# Add mod menu option "convert to new question"

Tags: feature-request, new-users, moderator-tools, new-questions

[image: a simulated display of what should be done]

I realize that this feature doesn't get used that often, but it happens often enough that on users with less than 100 rep I would like to migrate their new answers to questions in their own right, because as in this case, the user is new and trying to ask a question.

I'm ignoring the part about how this question is very poorly formatted and how it's lacking in details for now. But it would be nice if I had some other recourse besides leaving a comment asking them to do something they don't understand.

I have a secondary feature-request that I'll mention here, but the SE team may want to do that as two features:

When you migrate someone like this, and you inbox them, can the inbox go to a "how to ask new questions" page like the about page, or something. Or maybe hit them with a short popup-overlay on the new screen to ask them if they knew they could ask a new question by using the site's "Ask Question" button. (this secondary request is in keeping with the new metrics being collected about if users understand how to use the site, such as the new help dialogs)

Comment: I'm not sure this is such a good idea. If the user can't be bothered to check their inbox and ask it themselves, what are the chances the person will stick around to answer comments/accept an answer and such?

Comment: This is why I hate the search feature @Shog9

Comment: Leaving aside possible technical/philosophical issues like "how often does this happen", "how would you tag these", and "when did you last see an answer that would actually make a good question as is"... Are you sure that silently converting someone's "answer" into a question wouldn't be *more* confusing than a comment along the lines of "Please ask your question separately using the 'Ask Question' button in the top right."?

Comment: Most questions asked as answers are crap anyway

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+to+question @jco

Comment: @AnnaLear I would expect the core team to inbox notify them at the very least.

Comment: @Shog9 and yet "convert to new question" in the new-question title didn't yield that.

Comment: [omit unnecessary words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) @jco